# why i'm getting void type not allowed

Tags: java, printing

when I'm trying to print the method I get an error on second line saying
void type not allowed here

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(printMenu());
  }

 public static void printMenu(){

 System.out.println("***** Welcome to KAU Flight Reservation System *****"+
        "\n 1. Add Flight Details in the System"+
        "\n 2. Add Passenger Details in the System"+
        "\n 3. Make a new Booking"+
        "\n 4. Search and Print a Booking"+
        "\n 5. List Flight Status"+
        "\n 6. Exit from the System ");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two kinds of functions in java. Procedures which They don't return any value and Functions which  return value. when you adding the word void in the method declaration it means that this is a Procedures method and it doesn't return any values however the `System.out.print()` method require a parameter of `Object` kind.

your printMenu() method should be like this.

```
 public static String printMenu(){

 String menu = "***** Welcome to KAU Flight Reservation System *****"+
        "\n 1. Add Flight Details in the System"+
        "\n 2. Add Passenger Details in the System"+
        "\n 3. Make a new Booking"+
        "\n 4. Search and Print a Booking"+
        "\n 5. List Flight Status"+
        "\n 6. Exit from the System ";
return menu;

}
```

Comment: thank you so much, unfortunately my teacher wants me to use the void method

Comment: then simply call the printMenu() method without using System.out.println()

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `printMenu()` method inside `System.out.println()` which is expecting a String value. However, your printMenu() method is returning void.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printMenu());
}

public static String printMenu() {
    return ("***** Welcome to KAU Flight Reservation System *****"+
            "\n 1. Add Flight Details in the System"+
            "\n 2. Add Passenger Details in the System"+
            "\n 3. Make a new Booking"+
            "\n 4. Search and Print a Booking"+
            "\n 5. List Flight Status"+
            "\n 6. Exit from the System ");
}
```

For more information about return types check out this Oracle Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html
I would also recommend going through some of those tutorials, they are great at teaching some of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        printMenu();
    }

    public static void printMenu(){

         System.out.println("***** Welcome to KAU Flight Reservation System *****"+
                "\n 1. Add Flight Details in the System"+
                "\n 2. Add Passenger Details in the System"+
                "\n 3. Make a new Booking"+
                "\n 4. Search and Print a Booking"+
                "\n 5. List Flight Status"+
                "\n 6. Exit from the System ");

        }

}
```

You have already printed the menu with your printMenu function so you shouldn't call it inside the system.out.print function.